# AmCharts4: Multiple data arrays

Tags: amcharts4

In my application, I can view multiple charts at the same time. Those charts can be either displayed seperated or overlayed. Overlayed means, that those charts all are in the same chart-div, like this:
[image]

The problem is: if i want to add the data, i need to build an array out of all those datapoints, looking like this:

```
let data=[
{
    date:...,
    data1:...,
    data2:...,
    .....
},
{
    ....
}
]
```

But when i load it from the server, I have seperate data arrays which i have to merge. That means, I have to look at every single datapoint and create a new one in the "merged-array" if there is no datapoint at the given date.

Doing this with thousands of datapoints uses way too much resources. My question is: is it possible to supply multiple data arrays instead of only 1?

Comment: The only way you can provide multiple data arrays is to set your data at the [series level](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Series_specific_data) instead of at the chart level, assuming each array corresponds to a different series' dataset. Otherwise, you have to merge them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using series.data instead of chart.data solved the problem for me!